# jQuery / jQuery UI (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have googled this error, and everything says that it has to do with the order in which you reference your Jquery.js files. I am able to order my .js and .css files in a way that works, but I want to understand why it wont work this way:

**Here are my bundles:**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/jquery")
.Include("~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/menu.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/sortable.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/spinner.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/theme.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css"));

//Bundle all scripts
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/all")
   .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
   .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")
   .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

**Here is what gives me the Uncaught Reference Error**

```
<html>
   <head>
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery")
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- body content here -->
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/all")
   </body>
</html>
```

**Here is what DOES work for me:**

```
  <html>
     <head>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/all")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery")
     </head>
     <body>
        <!-- body content here -->
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: 1) It could be possible, that you somehow access jQuery in your body, which is loaded before the scripts at the end of the body, without wrapping it in a "onload"-event callback.
2) "~/Content/themes/base/jquery" - is this a js (which also might be trying to access jQuery) or is it a .css file too?

Comment: @newBee Content/themes/base/jquery is a style. U can see I am rendering it styles.render. As far as the onLoad function callback. I am using document.ready. Should that work too? Or must it be onLoad?

Comment: ```.ready``` is sufficient. Is there anything the body that accesses/uses jQuery? What is the exact line/statement that throws the error?